# Changing css Display property once a key is hit with javaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to add an event listener or something similar that changes the display of the `character` class in `CSS` from `none` to `grid` when a key is typed in the searchbar.
I've tried several ways but am not having much luck and am not quite sure how to work it in. I would also like to make the elements clickable. Any help would really be appreciated. Code

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>&#x2728;Harry Potter Characters &#x2728;</h1>
      <div id="searchWrapper">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="searchBar"
          id="searchBar"
          placeholder="search for a character"
        />
      </div>
      <ul id="charactersList"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #111d4a;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  color: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.container {
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}

#charactersList {
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.character {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: none;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "name"
    "house";
  text-align: left;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.character > h2 {
  grid-area: name;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.character > p {
  grid-area: house;
  margin: 0;
}

#searchBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#searchWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#searchWrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 15px;
}
```

JS

```
const charactersList = document.getElementById("charactersList");
const searchBar = document.getElementById("searchBar");
let hpCharacters = [];

searchBar.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

  const filteredCharacters = hpCharacters.filter((character) => {
    return character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString);
  });
  displayCharacters(filteredCharacters);
});

const loadCharacters = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("https://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters");
    hpCharacters = await res.json();
    displayCharacters(hpCharacters);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

const displayCharacters = (characters) => {
  const htmlString = characters
    .map((character) => {
      return `
            <li class="character">
                <h2>${character.name}</h2>
                <p>House: ${character.house}</p>
            </li>
        `;
    })
    .join("");
  charactersList.innerHTML = htmlString;
};

loadCharacters();
```

Comment: Basically, when you press a key you want to make a `<li class="character">` to be _**active**_ (visible). The best way to do that is to work at the high level of that concept, rather than twiddling with low-level attributes like the `display` value. So as @Wally answers, add (or toggle) a class so the element would become `<li class="character active">` and have a CSS rule that says `.character.active { display: grid; }` Bonus advantage: if you were to redesign and used a _flow_ layout, not grid, your _code_ would not have to change, just your CSS (which has to change anyway in a redesign)

Answer (score 0):

So

> So I want to add an event listener or something similar that changes the display of the display of the "character" class in css from "none" to "grid" when a key is typed in the searchbar.

You could do this by applying an eventlistener i.e the keypress event listener - and on that functions callback just use the `element.classlist.toggle` or `element.classlist.add` to add another class to the element which has the display of grid.

another method would also to be use the event listener for the keypress of your choice, but in the call back, edit the style of the element in question - so

```
addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      element.style.display="grid";

    // to make the element clickable - just add another event listener to it - 
    }
});
```

For any key being pressed the event listener is keydown -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event

```
addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        
          element.style.display="grid"; 
    
    });
```

Hope that helps -
W

Comment: Thanks! In the second option how do you make it work on any key instead of just enter?

Comment: as in on any key that is pressed regardless of what key it is? then that would be keypress - I've updated my answer

Comment: Yeah, as soon as a key any is pressed, there's a function that starts mapping through the data and populates a list in the html. Right now that list class ```character ``` is set to display none, and I want it change to ``` grid`` when any key is first entered into the searchbar. I'm sure the answer is in the code you provided but I haven't got it working yet.

Comment: put this into chrome dev tools - or any dev tools for an example :::: document.addEventListener('keypress', ()=>{ console.log('code will run') })

Comment: It returned undefined. This is the code I used outside of any other function but it didn't work ``` searchBar.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  character.style.display = "grid";
});``

Comment: gonna ask a silly question but the have you defined searchBar as a variable yet i.e. used something like querySelector('') to define it? if so - could you make an edit to your question above as show your working please :)m

Comment: Sorry yeah it's defined near the top of the javaScript code orignal comment, it doesn't seem to want to let me edit the replies. That code is ```const searchBar = document.getElementById("searchBar")``` Edit: but it lets me edit this one lol,  there's already an eventListener happening on the searchBar, maybe thats messing it up?

Comment: @Marcel 1) You can edit a comment for only a few minutes before it's "locked". 2) As long as you use `.addEventListener(...)` it won't get messed up to have more than one listener. 3) Where exactly does your JS live? In a `.js` file? In a `<script>` block? It is possible that `<input id="searchBar">` does not exist in the DOM yet when you add the code that is "outside of any other function" (from your earlier comment) 4) I again recommend toggling a class, not directly manipulating `element.style.display = "grid"`

Comment: Oh ic, thanks. It's in a .js file yeah running in vscode. The html seems to be loading fine so i assume it exists in the dom. How would I apply toggle then?

Comment: div.classList.toggle("grid");  <<< you'd need a class called grid in your css btw